# Entity framework code first migration to multiple database

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-6

Lets say we have the architecture model of web application where we have 1 database per 1 account. Database structure is the same for these accounts and differs only on data with in. How can i configurate a migrations in code first model.

Comment: You have different release branches for different accounts?

Comment: No, there are only one release branch for them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now I have next solution.
In the main method or in global.asax something like this:

```
    var migration_config = new Configuration();
    migration_config.TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo("BlogContext");
    var migrator = new DbMigrator(migration_config);
    migrator.Update();
    migration_config.TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo("BlogContextCopy");
    migrator = new DbMigrator(migration_config);
    migrator.Update();
```

Connection strings for example in app_config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="BlogContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Database=MigrationsDemo.BlogContext;Integrated Security=True;"/>
 <add name="BlogContextCopy" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Database=MigrationsDemo.BlogContextCopy;Integrated Security=True;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Configuration class and context:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MigrationsDemo.BlogContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(MigrationsDemo.BlogContext context) {
    }
}

public class BlogContext : DbContext {
    public BlogContext() {}
    public BlogContext(string connection_name) : base(connection_name) {
    }
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to your excellent answer, you can use an external config file (i.e. "clients.json") instead of hardcoding them, put all the database infos in key-value pairs into the json file and load it during startup.

Then, by iterating over the key-value pairs, you can do the initialization.

The `clients.json`:

```
{
  "DatabaseA": "DatabaseAConnectionString",
  "DatabaseB": "DatabaseBConnectionString",
  "DatabaseC": "DatabaseCConnectionString",
  ...
}
```

Provide a method to handle the migrations:

```
public static void MigrateDatabases(IDictionary<string,string> databaseConfigs)
{
  foreach (var db in databaseConfigs)
  {
    var config = new Configuration
    {
      TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(db.Value, "System.Data.SqlClient")
    };

    var migrator = new DbMigrator(config);
    migrator.Update();
  }
}
```

Then during startup, (I use OWIN, so it's in my `Startup.cs`, could also be `global.asax.cs`):

```
string json;
var path = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(path + @"Config\clients.json"))
{
   json = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

var databases = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, string>>(json);
MigrateDatabases(databases);
```

Works like a charm for me :)

Answer (score 0):

See [the page on automatic migrations during application startup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621#initializer).

If you use this method to apply your migrations, you can use any connection string (or whatever method you have to identify exactly which database to connect to) and upon connection, the migration will be performed.

Comment: How to inform the migration tool a list of databases which i need to update? Can you give some example?

Comment: If i'll type about 50 or 100 databases to connection strings section how migration tool will know which of them needs for migration?

Comment: Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<BlogContext, Configuration>()); doesn't work because it can update only one database

Comment: How does your application know which database to connect to normally? This should migrate whatever database you connect to *automatically*.

Comment: @Steve, I have a multi-tenant application as well and we have a single web application that has a database for each client.  We have a tenant initializer that determines which database name to inject into the connection string at runtime (it's based on the subdomain for us).  So, I'm in the same boat, how would one tell the migrations executor to loop through a list of connection strings or DbContexts?

Comment: @Keith It's been a long time since I've worked with EF. I'm not sure how you would iterate through all your connections, but if you simply connect to each database and do some simply query, it'll migrate it to the new schema.